# How to get fragment added in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a main fragment with following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map_fragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to get reference to `SupportMapFragment` in `MainFragment`. I do it like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mFragment1 = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map_fragment);
    mFragment2 = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map_fragment);
    ...
}
```

Both `mFragment1` and `mFragmanet2` are null. How to do it well?

**EDIT**
I am not sure if it is important or not but `MainFragment` is a child of another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

fragment with class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment, this fragment is used to display Android SupportMapFragment., so use getSupportFragmentManager()

```
    mFragment1 = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map_fragment);

replace with 

    mFragment1 = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map_fragment);
```

Comment: Umm, the "support" in "SupportMapFragment" and "getSupportFragmentManager()" are totally different concepts. The former is a class name, the latter is a method in FragmentActivity (part of the support library). The question didn't specify an API level, so assume he's using Activity and not FragmentActivity.

Comment: @foo64: SupportMapFragment extends v4.app.Fragment where as MapFragment extends Fragment. When ur using v4 one then u should use getSupportFragmentManager(). what is totally different concept here?

Comment: `SupportMapFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `public abstract android.support.v4.app.Fragment findFragmentById(int i)` so the types are ok.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not even inflating the main fragment.

```
View view = inflater.inflate( R.id.main_fragment, container, false );
mFragment2 = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map_fragment);
```

Comment: I inflated main fragment. But I skip these code in my example because it doesn't change anything.